# How to pass Model Attributes from Controller to Controller in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am creating a project in Spring MVC for accepting feedback form. I am accepting user values i.e name, email, phone & comments in 'home.jsp' page. Then I am passing those values to a controller 'feedback' and then I want to pass those values to another controller 'feedback2' and then finally to 'admin_panel.jsp. How should I pass values between the controllers?

I am accepting user values i.e name, email, phone & comments in 'home.jsp' page

***home.jsp***

```
<form action="feedback" method="post">
<input type="text" name="Name" value="Name " onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name';}" required="">
<input type="email" name="Email" value="Email" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email';}" required="">
<input type="text" name="Phone" value="Phone" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Phone';}" required="">
<textarea type="text" name="comments" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Special Instruction/Comments...';}" required="">Special Instruction/Comments...</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Then I am passing those values to a controller 'feedback' and then I want to pass those values to another controller 'feedback2' and then finally to 'admin_panel.jsp.

```
***HomeController.java***

package com.helloworld.mvc;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        return "home";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/feedback", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String feedback(@RequestParam("Name") String Name, @RequestParam("Email") String Email, @RequestParam("Phone") String Phone, @RequestParam("comments") String textarea, Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("Name",Name);
    model.addAttribute("Email",Email);
    model.addAttribute("Phone",Phone);
    model.addAttribute("textarea",textarea);
    return "feedback2";
}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/feedback2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String feedback2(@RequestParam("Name") String Name, @RequestParam("Email") String Email, @RequestParam("Phone") String Phone, @RequestParam("comments") String textarea, Model model)
    {
        return "admin_panel.jsp";
}
}
```

finally I am displaying the values on 'admin_panel.jsp.

```
***admin_panel.jsp***

<h1>Admin Panel</h1>
<h3>${Name}</h3>
<h3>${Email}</h3>
<h3>${Phone}</h3>
<h3>${textarea}</h3>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *passing values to a controller from a controller*? In Spring MVC, a controller receives a request, process it and passes control to a view to display the response. But you can call as many java methods you want in a controller...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to rethink your design (for instance, why has feedback2 to be an ReuqetMapping and not a simple method which is called by feedback), but you can foreward a request in Spring MVC by returnin as "view name"

```
forward:<new url>
```

In your case

```
forward:/feedback2
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only agree to what @Thomas Pawlitzki already said: Rethink your design. I'd expect the POST request mapping to directly return the view which shows success or error (`admin_panel.jsp` in your case).

Another tipp here: I highly recommend to not map your feedback data as `@RequestParam`. Create a class for the message payload and map it as `@RequestBody`. Your method signature will become much more simple:

```
public String feedback(@RequestBody Feedback feedback) {...}
```

If you - for whatever reason - need to pass model objects from one controller to another I'd suggest to use flash attributes. Pass an instance of `RedirectAttributes` to your feedback controller and add flash attributes via `redirectAttributes.addFlashAttriute(key, value)`. Then return `redirect:/feedback2`. All flash attributes will be available as model objects in feedback2 controller.